# Using awk to divide the number in each line of a file by the maximum value in that file

Tags: awk, arithmetic, numeric-data

I have a file like this:

```
0.0451660231
0.0451660231
0.0527343825
0.3933106065
0.3970947862
0.0489502028
0.3592529595
0.3592529595
0.3592529595
0.3630371392
0.3630371392
0.3668213189
0.4008789659
0.1397705227
```

and I want to divide each line by the maximum value.

I did

```
cut -f1 -d"," CVBR1_hist | sort -n | tail -1 > maximum
awk -v c=$maximum '{print $1/c}' CVBR1_hist > CVBR1_norm
```

I have this error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=CVBR1_hist FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted
```

I don't know how to solve it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should assign to a variable named `maximum` not redirect to a file named `maximum`. And what are you `cut`ting there ? There's only one field per line in your file

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awk give you an error because the variable "c" is set equal to an empty variable. $maximum isn't yet set.

You should do:

```
awk -v c=`cat maximum` '{print $1/c}' CVBR1_hist > CVBR1_norm
```

Here is where your command failed.

Better way: don't go through a temporary file but store the maximum value in a variable, like the [Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339785/167995).

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that sorting the contents of the file `CVBR1_hist` numerically generates the correct data:

```
$ sort -n CVBR1_hist
0.0451660231
0.0451660231
0.0489502028
0.0527343825
0.1397705227
0.3592529595
0.3592529595
0.3592529595
0.3630371392
0.3630371392
0.3668213189
0.3933106065
0.3970947862
0.4008789659
```

Then we may store the maximum in a variable using a command substitution like this:

```
maximum="$( sort -n CVBR1_hist | tail -n 1 )"
```

The normalized values may then be had with `awk`:

```
awk -v m="$maximum" '{ print $1/m }' CVBR1_hist >CVBR1_norm
```

So the only thing you were missing was the proper storing of the maximum in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-pass awk solution, but it stores all of the data in-memory in an array. Run it like: `awk -f thisprogram.awk < CVBR1_hist > CVBR1_norm`

```
{
  elements[NR]=$1
  if ($1 > largest) {
    largest = $1
  }
}
END {
  for(i=1; i <= NR; i++)
    printf "%.10f\n", elements[i]/largest
}
```

Comment: Begin statement wasn't necessary, since variable largest will be created dynamically. Also, I don't quite see what's the purpose of PROCINFO, but you generally got the right idea - linear search and arrays - therefore +1

Comment: Thanks, Serg; I don't work in awk often enough to be good at it. I wasn't sure if there was a better way of sorting the array numerically (keeping the original contents in order).

Comment: Serg made me stop and think a little bit more; the BEGIN stanza is gone, and the END stanza is greatly simplified and no longer uses a GNU-ism.